# Angular - Like/Dislike system for each Post using ngClass?

Tags: angular

0

Basically, I am doing a social network for my back-end school project however I came across this problem on the front end side of my app.

I have a newsfeed page and it has many posts. Each post has an area where you can give a like by clicking on the heart icon. On the server side it is working fine, however the problem here is the animation on once I click for like the heart gets filled with red and if I click again(for dislike) it removes the red collor which was filled.

Thank you in advance for your time to reading this.

Code

Template:

A little bit above this code I have an article with ngFor postsArray:

```
article *ngFor="let eachPost of allPostsArray; let i = index">

            <li (click)="likePost(eachPost.post_id, eachPost.isLiked, i)">
                <i *ngIf="eachPost.isLiked === false" class="far fa-heart" [ngClass]="(lastClickedIndex === i) ? 'fas fa-heart' : ''"></i>
                <i *ngIf="eachPost.isLiked === true" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                <span> {{eachPost.likesNumber}} </span>
            </li>                 

    </div>
```

Typescript file:

```
likePost(postId:number, isLiked: boolean, index){ console.log(isLiked);

this.lastClickedIndex = index;

this.allSubscritions.add(this.myUserActions.likeDislikePost(postId, this.connectedUserId).subscribe(responseData => {

  for (let index = 0; index < this.allPostsArray.length; index++) {

    let posicaoIndex = this.allPostsArray[index];
    if(posicaoIndex['post_id'] === postId){
      
      if(responseData['liked'] === true){
        posicaoIndex["likesNumber"]++
        
      } else {
        posicaoIndex["likesNumber"]--

      }
    }
  }

}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]` like so:

```
<article *ngFor="let eachPost of allPostsArray; let i = index">

        <li (click)="likePost(eachPost.post_id, eachPost.isLiked, i)">
            <i [ngClass]="{ 'far fa-heart': !eachPost.isLiked, 'fas fa-heart': eachPost.isLiked }"></i>
            <span> {{eachPost.likesNumber}} </span>
        </li>                 

</article>
```

Be aware that you might need to set up a proper update mechanism to `allPostsArray` for Angular to pick up the changes in like/dislike if you want the changes to be reflected dynamically.